# Comparing the quality of terminals

Tags: gnuplot, ps

I see that the quality of fill patterns change from one terminal to another. For example, This the shapes I see on `set term windows`

[image]

and this is what I see in `set term post eps enhanced color blacktext size 3.2,2.2 solid "Times-Roman" 12`

[image]

And when I print the `ps post` output on a paper, the lines are very thin.

The question is why and how can I have such pattern in ps term

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question is why and how can I such pattern in ps term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a matter of quality. The pattern styles are defined differently, I don't know why.

Here are two solutions for this:

1. You can first plot the pattern only with a larger `linewidth` setting, and after that the border:

   ```
   set terminal postscript eps monochrome
   set output 'foobar.eps'
   set samples 10
   set xrange [0:1]
   set boxwidth 0.9 relative
   set style data boxes
   plot '+' using 1:1 fillstyle pattern 4 noborder linewidth 10,\
        '+' using 1:1 lt 1 lw 2 fillstyle empty notitle
   ```

   That, however, gives you also different results for the `windows` terminal, if that matters.
2. You can change the file `prologue.ps`, which contains the definition of the pattern line width. See `show psdir` for the location of this file.

   With version 4.6.3, the `prologue.ps` file contains in lines 266 to 280 the respective definition:

   ```
   /PatternFill {gsave /PFa [ 9 2 roll ] def
   [...4 lines skipped]
   currentlinewidth 0.5 mul setlinewidth
   ```

   You must change this line to something like

   ```
   currentlinewidth 2 mul setlinewidth
   ```

   then save the `prologue.ps` file somewhere else, and set the correct directory with `set psdir`.

Comment: Yes the `noborder linewidth X` was easy to fix that